# What is the best way to save and publish version in Cloud Foundry app?

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

What is the best way to save and publish git version of Cloud Foundry app?
Is it possible to specify what version string aka git revision should be added to application metadata, and how to get this information outside of app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot there are plugins for maven and gradle to git information to the build.

Maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17"
}
```

The information will then be available on /info if you are using actuators

More information:https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/console/spring-boot-actuators.html

Comment: Not sure what language/frameworks are being asked about in this question, but Steeltole provides this for .NET & .NET Core apps.  http://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-management/